Installed thonny using sudo but can't run from desktop
Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
kubuntu 22.04
I downloaded the thonny bash script from thonny git.
from terminal i typed sudo bash thonny-4.1.4.bash
it installed fine.
If I run in terminal sudo /root/apps/thonny/bin/thonny it runs and opens fine.
If I try and run it from Kubuntu desktop I get an error that the file doesn't exist.  I'm guessing that as my user I don't have access to that file being that its in the root folder.
Question:
Why are files installed into root folder with root user:group permissions when I use sudo, if I can't be root to run the app from the desktop?
I always follow install instructions which always reference using sudo so
this goes for everything I do resulting in lots of permission denied errors but thats for another day.
Thanks for your help,
Kadam.

I think the installer is meant to install the program for a single user, so running it with sudo bash made it think the program was meant to be installed for root. Have you tried running the installer without sudo, just bash thonny-4.1.4.bash? It should install it for your user, making it possible to run it without sudo.

I would rather recommend to install Thonny via pip instead of the Bash script. This would also allow to update Thonny via pip. Plus it would allow to install the program systemwide without bumping into the problems experienced, although this may not be really recommendable

So I don't think this comment abides by the rules but I'm confused. I'm trying to accept an answer to my original post  and follow the instructions laid out in the help but there is no check mark to click on.  The help says you need to wait at least 15 mins but its been hours.  It also states that even though I'm new I should have the ability to mark "accepted" Do I need to wait longer?

Nobody answered your question, these are just comments, that's why you can't accept anything, how did you manage to solve this? Please let me or noisefloor using @ followed by our username which method worked for you so that we may be able to post an answer

I tried both methods mentioned above and they both worked, allowing my user to open thonny without using sudo. However, the method mentioned by @kos worked best as it produced a usable desktop link.  The method by noisefloor, using pip, adds a few more steps to run Thonny since you need to run it using "python3 -m thonny" from terminal and not the desktop. I'm sure there's other ways but I'm not too familiar with pip either.

I posted an answer below, I'll ping @noisefloor so that if they want they may post an answer as well, as their method worked out for you as well, once they've done this please upvote both answers and pick either one as the accepted answer, so that user stumbling upon this question in the future will be aware that our answers are an actual solution to the problem. Thanks!

Some installers may attempt to install the application just for the user running the installer, which is what happened here;
Unnecessarily running bash thonny-4.1.4.bash with sudo made Bash run as root and in a modified envinroment;
I'm not claiming one of these methods was the one used by the installer to determine the target user / the target user's home directory to which install the files, but, for example, here are some things that may look different to a shell spawned with sudo:
% sudo bash -c 'printenv' | grep -P '^(HOME|USER)='
HOME=/root # the $HOME environment variable
USER=root # the $USER environment variable
% sudo bash -c 'id -u'
0 # the effective user's UID
% sudo bash -c 'id -un'
root # the effective user's username

The solution, simply, would be to run the script without sudo:
bash thonny-4.1.4.bash

